# VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 apache2 vhost jumping to https or not showing the page

Tags: apache, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I am trying to set up some vhosts on a Virtual Box with Ubuntu 16.04 Apache2 PHP 7.0 to start moving the code to PHP7.

I have moved the v-host file from the older VBox which looked like this

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.174:80>
    ServerName admin.ubuntu16.de
    ServerAlias admin.ubuntu16.de
    ServerAdmin email@company.de
    DocumentRoot /home/www/public_html/workspace/admin

    php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/www/public_html/workspace/admin/administration/conf/register_globals.php'

    <Directory /home/www/public_html/workspace/admin>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        Options All
        AllowOverride  All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it kept on trying to load the page with https or saying that there is no access to site root folder

These settings work perfectly on Ubuntu 14 Virtuall Box with apache2 and PHP 5.5.something

So I followed the tutorial and changed it to simply

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.174:80>
    ServerName admin.ubuntu16.de
    ServerAlias admin.ubuntu16.de
    ServerAdmin email@company.de
    DocumentRoot /home/www/public_html/workspace/admin
</VirtualHost>
```

But now it just jumps straight to https mode

I obviously ran a2ensite
I also switched off the default site by running "a2dissite 000-default.conf"

I also enable modules to do with proxying and a bunch of others while getting appache to actuallly start :-)

Any ideas on things I might off missed are greatly appreciated.

Just a little edit:
All the files for the sites are situated on the main Windows machine and are imported through /media/sf-workspace
The symbolic link is then created as /home/www/public_html/workspace

Answer (score 0):

I would first eliminate the symbolic links and just make a copy of all the files inside the virtual box to remove that variable.

Apache can be screwy with symlinks.

Comment: I tried copying the php files into /home/www/public_html/ folder.

But when I tried refreshing the browser it still sent me to 'h.t.t.p.s://admin.ubuntu16.de'

And I am buffled by being sent to https as it has not been set up.